# Blacklist domains in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, blacklist

I found a guide that helps blacklist certain domains from accsessing your site ,

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://.*somebadforum\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://.*example\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://.*lastexample\.com [NC]
```

The problem is it does not say if it is including subdomains.

We have websites that are trying to attack us by placing an image link to nonexisting files on our website which results in 404 errors and a couple thousand hits making us toast.

We cant even find IP on some of them and some IP to google US

Domains are :

```
someblo.blogspot DOT com
someblo.blogspot DOT com DOT br
someblo.blogspot DOT com DOT mn

someblo.blogspot,gogo DOT mn
```

Can someone please enlighten us so we can block them?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at here [5G Blacklist 2013](http://perishablepress.com/5g-blacklist-2013/). It may help you.